# Override value in the form using yup when condition applies

Tags: javascript, formik, yup

I am trying to build a `yup` validation schema, but I couldn't figure out how to transform value to a default every time when it doesn't match the schema.

I was trying to check is value `higher than 0` and `not undefined`, so then this form value would be required, otherwise I would like to set it to the empty string.

This is my code:

```
reason: string()
 .when('value', {
  is: val => Boolean(val),
  then: string().required('This field is required'),
  otherwise: string().transform((value) => value ? value : '')
})
```

Thanks a lot!